# Failing fetch request with ofx body

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, fetch

Probably Im missing something
trying to run fetch request in react app with XML OFX body,
the POSTMAN request is passing successfully but fetch returning 404.
example:

```js
    const body = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><OFX><SIGNONMSGSRQV1>...some body </SIGNUPMSGSRQV1></OFX>';
    const url = '10.10.10.110'// fake address
     fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      mode: 'cors',
      body: body,
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-ofx'
      }
    }).then((res)=>{
      console.log(res.status);
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log('Err', err);
    })
```

the body: JSON.stringify(body)
giving the same 404;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find out the way to send that request using fetch
Problem id header.
you cannot send ofx in the header

```js
const body = `<OFX>...request body...</OFX>`;
    const url = 'http://requestserver';
     return fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      body: body,
      mode: 'cors',
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8"'
      }
```